# For loop is not working properly in javascript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loops

I am working with php and ajax,I am getting ajax response( as ["463","500","505"] ) and i am trying to pass this via loop but loop is working only single time instead of three
Here is my code,Where i am wrong ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url:'<?php echo base_url();?>Main/GetFollowingCoinUsers',
    data: {coin_id:coin_id},
    success: function (datan) {
        //datan contaning values like - ["463","500","505"]
        var str_array = datan.split(',');
        var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8282');
        var client = {
            user_id: <?php echo $number; ?>,
            recipient_id: null,
            NotificationType: 'notification',
            type: 'socket',
            token: null,
            message: null
        };

        conn.onopen = function (e) {
            conn.send(JSON.stringify(client));
        };
            
        for (var i=0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
            client.message = 'notifications';
            client.token = '';
            client.type = 'chat';
            client.recipient_id = str_array[i].send(str_array.toString());
            conn.send(JSON.stringify(client));  
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try using let instead of var

Comment: I dont think u need `split()` for the response, try directly using datan.